# Jackson custom deserializer null codec

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have wrote custom deserializer for my type, which is represented as `interface Attachment` and there are two implementions of this interface `Photo` and `Video`.
When parsing I recognize them from json using discriminator field.

Now I'm facing problem when `jp.getCodec()` returns `null`, leading
to `null pointer exception`

Why this is happining and how to fix it?

```
public class AttachmentDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Attachment> {

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public AttachmentDeserializer() {
    this(null);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
  }

  public AttachmentDeserializer(Class<Attachment> t) {
    super(t);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
  }

  @Override
  public Attachment deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);

    String type = node.get("type").asText();

    switch (type) {
      case "photo":
        return new AttachmentPhoto(
            node.get("t").asInt(),
            objectMapper.readValue(node.get("photo").traverse(), Photo.class));

      case "video":
        return new AttachmentVideo(
            node.get("t").asInt(),
            objectMapper.readValue(node.get("video").traverse(), Video.class));

      default:
        throw ctxt.weirdStringException("type", Attachment.class, "Unknown discriminator");
    }
  }
}
```

The attachmentPhoto code:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class AttachmentPhoto implements Attachment {

  private Photo photo;

  public Attachments what() {
    return Attachments.ATTACHMENT_PHOTO;
  }

  public String getDiscriminator() {
    return "photo";
  }

  public AttachmentPhoto() {}

  public AttachmentPhoto(Photo photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
  }

  public Photo getPhoto() {
    return this.photo;
  }

  public AttachmentPhoto setPhoto(Photo v) {
    this.photo = v;
    return this;
  }

  public boolean isAttachmentPhoto() {
    return true;
  }

  public AttachmentPhoto asAttachmentPhoto() {
    return this;
  }

  public boolean isAttachmentVideo() {
    return false;
  }

  public AttachmentVideo asAttachmentVideo() {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Not a $stName: " + this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object thatObj) {
    if (this == thatObj) return true;

    if (!(thatObj instanceof AttachmentPhoto)) return false;

    AttachmentPhoto that = (AttachmentPhoto) thatObj;

    return this.photo.equals(that.photo);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "AttachmentPhoto{" + "photo=" + this.photo + '}';
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the constructor of AttachmentPhoto or AttachmentVideo? Need to know how the super is called

Comment: I fixed the bug changing `.traverse()` to `.traverse(jp.getCodec())`

Answer (score 0):

Your default constructor looks very suspicious for two reasons, first it calls the second constructor with null class type which then passes the null type to the superclass hence the overridden generic method is messed up when this constructor is used. Secondly, it does no useful work since it already calls the other constructor that initializes `objectMapper`. You should remove the first constructor and remain with just the typed one and initialize your deserializer using that.

Comment: I fixed the bug changing `.traverse()` to `.traverse(jp.getCodec())`